# Change the style of navbar on route change

Tags: reactjs, rendering, use-effect, tailwind-css

I am using this code to change the style of the navbar when it routes to different pages.

But if I use the below code page becomes unresponsive because of re-rendering. If I pass an empty [] or pass location as the second element in useEffect, then it doesn't work.

**So what is the alternative for this?**

```
const [active, setActive] = React.useState(false);
const location = useLocation();

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (location.pathname === "/Catalogues" || location.pathname === "/About") {
    setActive(true);
  }
});
return (
  <>
    <nav className={active ? "bg-white" : "bg-black"}>
      <div>.....</div>
    </nav>
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need setActive, but more importantly location as a dependency of the useEffect

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
            if ((location.pathname === "/Catalogues") || (location.pathname === "/About")) {
                setActive(true);
            }
        }, [location, setActive]);
```

Edit: it seems very unnecessary to have active in local state
you can simply set a const like so

```
 const isActive = (location.pathname === "/Catalogues") || (location.pathname === "/About");
```

Then delete the useEffect and useState

Answer (score 1):

**You need not necessarily use `state` for this functionality:**

```
const location = useLocation();
let active = false;

if (location.pathname === "/Catalogues" || location.pathname === "/About") {
  active = true;
}

return (
  <>
    <nav className={active ? "bg-white" : "bg-black"}>
      <div>.....</div>
    </nav>
  </>
);
```